# ¿Existe en Español una palabra para "una forma de tratar con un problema o hacer funcionar algo a pesar del problema, sin resolverlo completamente"?

Tags: solicitud-de-término

En Inglés existe la palabra "workaround" que significa,

> una forma de tratar con un problema o hacer funcionar algo a pesar del
> problema, sin resolverlo completamente

[Workaround](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/workaround)

Google traduce esta palabra como "solución alterna" o "solución alternativa", pero este término carece de la connotación de "parche" que tiene la palabra original.

¿Existe en Español una palabra para "una forma de tratar con un problema o hacer funcionar algo a pesar del problema, sin resolverlo completamente"?

Answer (score 2):

No me parece que "solución alternativa" sea una traducción correcta de "workaround". Al menos no en el sentido de superar un problema (rodearlo) sin realmente resolverlo.

En contexto formal usaría la ya mencionada "solución provisional/temporal".

Informalmente, "parche" o "apaño". Y en informática, al menos en España, se usa mucho "ñapa", que, curiosamente, viene del quechua.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar "solución provisional".  Si buscas la traducción de "stopgap",  produce esta frase, además de "parche".

Answer (score 0):

En España tenemos una expresión que utilizamos bastante y es "**chapuza**", "**hacer chapuzas**", "**chapucear**", "**chapucero**", este último sería el que realiza las chapuzas.

La palabra "chapuza" o "hacer chapuzas" posee varias connotaciones y no todas recogidas en la RAE:

Así por una parte tiene la acepción de hacer algo de manera rápida y mal, sin mucho esmero, de esta forma se entiende generalmente que "**hacer chapuzas**" son trabajos rápidos y mal hechos.

Ese sentido y por esa misma razón, "**la de ser trabajos precarios**", también lleva la implícita idea de que son trabajos no profesionales ideados por cualquiera que no sea un profesional para dar una solución a un problema con carácter temporal, que a veces suele prolongarse en el tiempo.

Por tanto decimos "**chapuza**" a aquellos arreglos que se realizan de forma no profesional y en principio con un carácter temporal, hasta que más tarde o en otro momento alguien más especializado venga a solucionarlo del todo o de una manera más profesional.

Esto puede ser ampliado a cualquier objeto, desde una aspiradora hasta que se hayan fundido los fusibles y no haya luz, convirtiéndose uno mismo o cualquiera que no sea profesional o no ducho en la materia, en un "**chapuzas**",  es decir, alguien que busca soluciones para arreglar algo de manera alternativas. Por ejemplo, en el caso de que se hayan fundido los "plomos" el fin de semana, y se haya ido la luz, liar en el fusible algún tipo de conector como son hilos de cobre, hasta que pueda venir el profesional que es el electricista o podamos ir a comprarlos el lunes a la tienda.

**España, un país entre los mejores** "**chapuceros**" (arreglos temporales para seguir funcionando, mientras vienen los especialistas técnicos para solucionarlos).

No hace mucho la televisión emitió un programa donde varias empresas internacionales japonesas, cuando tenían problemas y no sabían como solucionarlos, preferían consultar a empresas españolas.

Esto ocurría sobre todo los fines de semana, cuando la mayoría de su personal de mantenimiento no estaba en servicio y tenían problemas de difícil solución.

La razón que daban es que los españoles eran muy buenos en improvisar y dar soluciones temporales para seguir funcionando mientras llegaba el lunes y sus equipos de mantenimiento se pudieran hacer cargo o pudieran llamar a personal más especializado. Algunas de estas empresas ya habían aprendido el sentido de las palabra "chapuza" y era gracioso ver cuando llamaban para consultar  y hablaban directamente de la necesidad que tenían de "**hacer una chapuza**" (arreglo temporal para seguir funcionando) por un problema sucedido.